# How do you pronounce 'vegan'?

Tags: pronunciation

Theoretically, there are four possible pronunciations of 'vegan' due to two syllables constituting this word, namely, 've'('vee' or 'vay'?) and 'gan'('gun' or 'gen' as in 'generate'?).

The online dictionary merriam-webster.com provides several pronunciations of 'vegan' but as you can see that there are several comments about it at the bottom.

Do you have any idea about this problem ?

Comment: Our son is a vegan and he pronounces it *vee-gn*.

Comment: http://www.forvo.com/word/vegan/#en

Comment: Vegan rhymes with [Megan](http://www.pronouncenames.com/pronounce/megan), a girl's name.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I pronounce Megan like mehgan. I've never (rarely) heard Meegan, and certainly not vehgan. But I'm sure someone does :).

Comment: @SrJoven we...ll, I thought it was the "ghen" or /ɡən/ sound which our friend was most confused with (shrugs shoulders).

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're close though. I was confused with both~^_^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pronounced [ˈviːɡən], see and listen [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vegan). The Longman Pronunciation Dictionary lists no other, alternative pronunciations for vegan.

Comment: Well, it's strange for me why it's pronounced totally differently from its nearest neighbor-'vegetarian'.

Comment: @booksee The *g* in *vegan* is not followed by an *e* as it is in *vegetarian*. That's one reason.

Comment: @booksee Some words even have alternative pronunciations.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, this is what I can think of to try to persuade myself, but in view of their meanings, I'm still reluctant to accept the difference in pronunciation.

Comment: @booksee - There are four exceptions to the rule than a "g" should be hard when followed by a vowel other than "i" or "e": *gaol*, *margarine*, *mortgagor* and *algae*. Of those, one is an archaic spelling that has mostly been replaced by *jail* (and which has changed pronunciation over the years), one is a derivative of Law French (where the *or* has replaced *eur* in English), and the other two are just plain weird pronunciations of borrowed foreign words.

Comment: @Booksee There are at least two other reasons. The first is that it was a deliberately invented word. The second is that in *vegetarian*, the stress in on the penultimate syllable due to the stress rule relating to the suffix.

Comment: FYI: the Longman Pronunciation dictionary does not mention any other pronunciations (it usually gives a complete list of all variations).

Comment: Does this answer apply only to 'Vegan' meaning 'a kind of food faddist', or is this also how you would pronounce 'Vegan' meaning 'a person from Vegas' (largest city in Nevada) or 'a being from Vega' (brightest star in the Lyre)?

Comment: Yeah, the Longman pronunciation is the way I usually hear it pronounced by people who are one (though I've heard all sorts of variations).

Answer (score 1):

As a carnivore (93, healthy, and fully expecting to reach 100) I find the pronunciation veegan to be as odd as the practice.  It conforms to no rules of English or common sense and doesn't make a newcomer to the word think of vegetarianism, which is presumably the intent.  The founder's pronunciation doesn't follow the rules well either, but at least it makes a sort of sense.  I recommend it.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your answer! 20 years are still ahead of me from half of your age...Glad you are healthy~

Comment: The pronunciation /viːgən/ conforms as exactly as is possible to the ‘rules’ (or better: hints) to inferring pronunciation from orthography in English.

Answer (score 0):

ACTUALLY, the the correct pronunciation is VEH-jen, with a short-e and soft-G! It's from vegetarian, and vegetable, of course, so it makes complete etymological and logical sense. This was the original pronunciation in the 70's (when I, personally, first heard it used), and nobody I knew back then ever heard of or used any other pronunciation. Somehow the wrong pronunciation got out (VEE-gan, with long-e and hard-g), likely from someone who saw it in print and didn't know the correct pronunciation, and now it's what people use ... still, it's not correct. Though common-usage for a living language is indeed ultimately what we go by, so ... In any case, look the pronunciation up in dictionaries from the 70s and 80s; by the mid-80s a second pronunciation was given, but the short-e and soft-g was still the first.﻿

Comment: That's interesting; do you have any specific sources though that you would point to for others to read?

Comment: ACTUALLY, that is nonsense. In the 1970s, the term had already been in use for three decades, and the _original_ pronunciation is /viːgən/, with a long ee-sound and a hard g. That is how its [coiner, Donald Watson, pronounced it](http://www.vegparadise.com/24carrot610.html), and since he and his wife invented the word, theirs must be considered the original. That doesn't really matter, though, because the correct pronunciation of a word is **not** necessarily the original one, but the one people use. They happen to be the same here.

Answer (score 0):

Hm.

The word was coined by Donald Watson, co-founder of the Vegan Society, by taking the first and last syllable of the word vegetarian.  He also suggested, and practiced, that it should be pronounced like the first and last syllable also.  Vedge in

From there, it's all bets off.

I've been vegan for over 30 years, with many Peers, and from the 70's through the early 90's, I never heard anyone pronounce it any way other than Vay gn.

That's my two carrot's worth.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Do you have any reference link that can support your answer? Please include it and make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: He did not. He specifically stated on multiple occasions that it should be pronounced /viːgən/. One such occasion is [this one](http://www.vegparadise.com/24carrot610.html).

Answer (score -2):

"Vee-gan". it kind of rhymes with norwegian.

Answer (score -4):

PEOPLE! Remember the basic rule in elementary school? If 2 vowels are separated by only one consonant, the first vowel is long. I am well aware that there are many exceptions to this rule but The word in question is vegan which adheres to the rule exactly. It's pronounced "VEE-gan" (with a hard 'g').

Comment: This answer has already been given, and with far more grace.

Comment: You realise that there are no less than **eight** exceptions to your so-called ‘rule’ in just the two first lines of this answer, right?